# VBA: GoalSeek Equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, excel, porting, vba

Does anyone know of a C# equivalent for VBA GoalSeek?

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/solverfoundation/) might be something of interest to you.

If you're specific about what you want, you may get a better answer.